# Python convert String to Variable in the loop

Tags: python

I would like to do something like this:

```
x = 0
y = 3

TEST0 = 10 
TEST1 = 20 
TEST2 = 30

while x < y:
    result = exec('TEST{}'.format(x))
    print(result)
    x += 1
```

And have the output:

```
10
20
30
```

Somehow convert `TEST{variable}` to the actual variable, or what is the way to do it?

Currently, I have result as:

```
None
None
None
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using a `list` with items `10`, `20`, and `30`?

Comment: Instead of calling `exec()`, call `eval()` to get the result you expect. Having said that, you almost certainly don't want to do it that way. Use a more appropriate data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Python! What you need is a *list*:

```
x = 0
y = 3

TEST = [10, 20, 30]

while x < y:
    result = TEST[x]
    print(result)
    x += 1
```

A list is created by putting the values between `[]`. You access a particular element in the list by writing the name of the variable, followed by the index enclosed in `[]`. Read more about lists [here in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Instead of the `while` loop with explicit indexing, it's nicer to use a `for` loop instead:

```
TEST = [10, 20, 30]

for element in TEST:
    result = element
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you (that will solve my current issue), but is it any other way to do it, without using the list?

Comment: There is, but it's fairly advanced and needlessly complex and error-prone. See the answer by @JosephChotard.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a dictionary in most cases, however if you don't want to use a dictionary you can always use `globals()` or `vars()`. They work as follows:

```py
global_var = 5
>> 5
print(globals()["global_var"])
>> 5
```

`vars()` works in the same way but at module scope.

In your case, do the following:

```py
x = 0
y = 3

TEST0 = 10 
TEST1 = 20 
TEST2 = 30

while x < y:
    result = globals()['TEST{}'.format(x)]
    print(result)
    x += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, (sorry do not have enough reputation to upvote). Have marked as an answer not your reply, to make sure that in the future other people will stick with a list (Sorry again)